# Get next 2 values for sequence in single row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

MSSQL 2014

I am performing a split on records in sql. The key of the table `MyTable` is generated by a sequence `MySeq`. Given a set of records, I want to generate 2 new keys that I can then do some work with then insert child rows.

```
MyTable
+----+
| Id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
|  2 |
```

Now to select my two new keys:

```
SELECT Id,
       NEXT VALUE FOR MySeq AS ChildId1,
       NEXT VALUE FOR MySeq AS ChildId2
  FROM MyTable
```

I want:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| Id | ChildId1 | ChildId2 |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |        3 |        4 |
+----+----------+----------+
|  2 |        5 |        6 |
```

I get:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| Id | ChildId1 | ChildId2 |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |        3 |        3 |
+----+----------+----------+
|  2 |        4 |        4 |
```

I think the reason for the single run of the sequence per row has something to do with the design of the feature. For example, it looks like you can order the sequence runs separately from the `SELECT`.

I have a work around that is fine enough (update the table var after initial `INSERT`), but before I left it that way, I thought I would see if there is a more natural way to get the result I am looking for.

Comment: `NEXT VALUE FOR` is only evaluated once per row. [This is documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx) : `the same value will be returned for all columns referencing the same sequence within a row in the result set.`.

Comment: (Not sure why the downvote, this seems a pretty understandable way to interpret how SEQUENCE works, and the actual behavior is IMHO unexpected and subtle.)

Comment: @Aaron. Ty for the clarification. I did go through the page and expected this was the case. I did not see the confirmation. I should have made it clear I was looking for a nicer work around for my case (like the awesome answer GurV added).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do in this situation is make the sequence to increment by two

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MySeq AS 
INT
START WITH 0 
INCREMENT BY 2;
```

and then do a:

```
SELECT Id, 
  NEXT VALUE FOR MySeq AS ChildId1, 
  1 + NEXT VALUE FOR MySeq AS ChildId2 
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Nice workaround. If you also want the second column to always be the first column + 1, you could just have a computed column.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong (as my MSSQL experience is limited... I mainly use other SQL programs) but could you not simply solve this with a couple of selects within selects?

i.e.:

```
SELECT ID, ((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MyTable)+ID) AS ChildId1, 
           ((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MyTable)+ID+1) AS ChildId2 
FROM MyTable
```